# How save mapped objects in Entity Framework using AutoMapper?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5, automapper

I'm trying using AutoMapper. I need to save mapped object, but I don't know how do it. How to implement this?

```
using (TestEntities context = new TestEntities())
{    
  SomeClass model = new SomeClass{...};

  SomeClassDto modelDto = Mapper.Map<SomeClass, SomeClassDto>(model);

  context.SomeClass.Add(modelDto); // ???
  context.SaveChanges();    
}
```

Comment: Your code seems correct. What error you have got?

Comment: cannot convert from 'SomeClassDto' to 'SomeClass'

Comment: Have you created map first?

Comment: `context.SomeClass` contains objects of type **`SomeClass`** and you're trying to add an object of type **`SomeClassDto`** to it - won't work.